# Specify a specific entry type in paramaters

Tags: craft3, search, sections, entry-type, params

I am currently searching within multiple sections on my site.

I'd like to limit one of the sections (`courses`) to a specific entry type (`cce`)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```php
{% set params = { 
    section: [ 'pages', 'careerPaths', 'courses', 'events', 'eventsIndex', 'news', 'newsIndex', 'programs', 'allPrograms', 'facultyStaff', 'facultyStaffIndex' ], 
    limit: siteVariables.resultsLimitForPagination 
} %}

{# if search term exists, search #}
{% set searchTerm = craft.app.request.getParam('q') %}

{% if searchTerm|length %}
    {% set params = params|merge({ groupBy: ['title'] }) %}
    {% set params = params|merge({ search : searchTerm, orderBy: 'score DESC'}) %}
{% endif %}

{# Query #}
{% set query = craft.entries(params)  %}

{% paginate query as pageInfo, entries %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the only way to do this at the moment would be to look up the `EntryType`s for each of the desired Sections, and filter just by those—ignoring the `section` query facet. For example:

```
{# Map some Section handles into actual Section models, using the Sections Service: #}
{% set sections = ['one', 'two', 'three'] | map((h) => craft.app.sections.getSectionByHandle(h) %}

{# List your "forbidden" Entry Types in a `sectionHandle:entryTypeHandle` format, so we can filter them out, in a moment: #}
{% set forbiddenEntryTypes = [
  'mySection:entryTypeOne',
  'mySection:entryTypeTwo'
] %}

{% set entryTypes = [] %}

{% for section in sections %}
  {# Get the section's EntryTypes, filtering out any that don't match our "magic" `section:entryType` values in the "forbidden" array, above: #}
  {% set permittedSectionEntryTypes = section.getEntryTypes() | filter((t) => "#{section.handle}:#{t.handle}" not in forbiddenEntryTypes) %}

  {# Merge anything that passes the test into the main `entryTypes` array: #}
  {% set entryTypes = entryTypes | merge(permittedSectionEntryTypes) %}
{% endfor %}

{% set query = craft.entries({
  type: entryTypes
}) %}
```

This basically works by assuming you want *all types from all sections*, then filtering out just a few types from that list.

For example, your `forbiddenEntryTypes` might look something like this, if you had three other Entry Types in the Courses section…

```
{% set forbiddenEntryTypes = [
  'courses:night',
  'courses:takeHome'
] %}
```

…where `cce` is allowed, because it's returned by the section, but not explicitly filtered out. You'll have to update this if/when you add more Course types!

> **Keep in mind** that the `sectionHandle:entryTypeHandle` format is not a Craft feature, it's just a way for us to compare Section + Entry Type handles at once (note the way we build the `"#{section.handle}:#{t.handle}"` string when filtering down the Entry types)!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the help August!

I was able to get this work as intended. The only issue we ran into was getting an error for {type: entryTypes} when it was an an array of EntryTypes.

Here is the finished code:

```
{% set sections = [ 'pages', 'careerPaths', 'courses', 'events', 'eventsIndex', 'news', 'newsIndex', 'programs', 'allPrograms', 'facultyStaff', 'facultyStaffIndex' ] | map((h) => craft.app.sections.getSectionByHandle(h)) %}

{# List your "forbidden" Entry Types in a `sectionHandle:entryTypeHandle` format, so we can filter them out, in a moment: #}
{% set forbiddenEntryTypes = [
    'courses:standard',
    'courses:cceCertificate'
] %}

{% set entryTypes = [] %}

{% for section in sections %}
    {# Get the section's EntryTypes, filtering out any that don't match our "magic" `section:entryType` values in the "forbidden" array, above: #}
    {% for entryType in section.getEntryTypes() | filter((t) => "#{section.handle}:#{t.handle}" not in forbiddenEntryTypes) %}
        {% set entryTypes = entryTypes | merge([entryType.handle])%}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}

{# dd entryTypes #}
{% set params = params|merge({ type: entryTypes }) %}
```

Comment: Nice! Alternatively, as you merge the value in with you query, you could use `entryTypes | column('id')` so that you're not discarding any actionable info until the last moment—using `id` may also prevent additional queries, as the `handle` ultimately needs to get mapped to an ID anyway! (This may well be cached/memoized on the Sections service…)